# Regex matches processing in R

Tags: regex, r

I would like to extract the 2 matching groups using R.
Right now I've got this, but is not working well:

Code:

```
str = '123abc'
vector <- gregexpr('(?<first>\\d+)(?<second>\\w+)', str, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(str, vector)
```

Result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "123abc"
```

I want the result to be something like this:

```
[1] "123"
[2] "abc"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you have a specific reason for using `regmatches`, unless you are e.g. importing the expressions in that format. If well-defined groups are common to all your entries, you can match them in this way:

```
x <- "123abc"
sub("([[:digit:]]+)[[:alpha:]]+","\\1",x)
sub("[[:digit:]]+([[:alpha:]]+)","\\1",x)
```

Result

```
[1] "123"
[1] "abc"
```

I.e., match the entire structure of the string, then replace it with the part you want to retain by enclosing it in round brackets and referring to it with a backreference ("\\1").

Comment: or, in one line: `strsplit(sub("([[:digit:]]+)([[:alpha:]]+)", "\\1 \\2", x), " ")[[1]]`

Comment: Right you are, of course... I wanted to keep the cases separate for clarity. (Also I'd probably `unlist` that result because 1-element lists get my goat :p)

Answer (score 1):

I've renamed your string `s` to avoid clobbering `str`.  Here is one approach:

```
library(stringr)
s <- '123abc'
reg <- '([[:digit:]]+)([[:alpha:]]+)'

complete <- unlist(str_extract_all(s, reg))
partials <- unlist(str_match_all(s, reg))
partials <- partials[!(partials %in% complete)]

partials
[1] "123" "abc"
```

Comment: I think using `str_match` will generalise a little better, because you'll get a matrix, and you can just drop the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how well structured your inputs are, you may want to use `strsplit` to split the string.

Documentation [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapplyc("123abc", '(\\d+)(\\w+)')[[1]]
[1] "123" "abc"
```